# Changing the Top menu in Vbulletin with Green SEO Theme

Tags: vbulletin

I'm trying to change my top menu in Vbulletin  
(under the logo, where it's currently saying Forum)

My theme is Green SEO Theme.

ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=235265&highlight=navbar

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't find what they're talking about.. I think it's something else